# Why does javascript automatically convert underscore characters in strings to blanks. I'm using node.js 9.8.0 on linux

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having an issue where any underscore character that appears in a string gets automatically converted to a blank. For example, if I have the following:

```
console.log('This_is_a_sample_string')
```

I get **`This is a sample string`** printed on the console instead. I realized this was happening when I used `Object.keys()` on a JSON object such as the following:

```
person {
   first_name: 'John',
   last_name: 'Doe'
}
```

The keys I got were `first name` and `last name` respectively. This is definitely not what I expected; especially when I tried to use those keys to do a query on a PostgreSQL table that has fields named `first_name` and `last_name`.

I have even tried using `JSON.stringify()` but i find that the underscores still get converted to blanks.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? Or is this behavior normal?

Comment: I just ran this console.log on 9.8.0. I am getting the the underscores. Can you post some surrounding code?

Comment: Can you try in different terminals and confirm that it really a issue across terminals you use ?

Comment: Are you seeing underscores at all in your console (from other sources)?

Comment: The fact that you are running this is Node really has nothing to do with it. JavaScript is JavaScript and underscores are legal in a string as well as in an identifier. This most likely is a simple display issue related to your font.

Comment: It's definitely not a console or font issue because when I try to use the key as part of an SQL query if fails with a database error stating that I have a syntax error near the field name. This is due to the fact that the field name doesn't match or exist for that matter since the underscores get stripped.  I ran the exact same code on node running on Windows and it works just fine. So I wonder if it is some environment configuration or a bug maybe?

Comment: what IDE do you use? could it be that your IDE shows you underscores where actually are none? For some IDEs you can configure how different types of whitespace are rendered/replaced.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm a noob! It turns out it was probably a font issue indeed. I'm using Visual Studio Code 1.21.0 under Antergos Linux. I installed nvm and installed the latest node LTS (8.10.0 at this moment) and my code still didn't work for me. However after some tinkering, I found out that the SQL error I was getting was due to an actual query mistake I had and not because the underscores were stripped (because apparently they were not). So even though I still can't see underscores in my console (which I run within Visual Studio Code), I fixed MY error and everything works as I expected now.